leaderstats is not a valid member of RBXScriptSignal
При запуске игры вылазит такая ошибка:
leaderstats is not a valid member of RBXScriptSignal

-- Создаем переменную для баланса 
local Players = game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded 

local sound = script.Parent.ImageButton.Sound 
local balance = game.Players.PlayerAdded.leaderstats.Balance 
     
-- Получаем ImageButton и TextLabel 
local imageButton = script.Parent.ImageButton 
local textLabel = script.Parent.TextLabel 
     
-- Устанавливаем начальное значение баланса 
balance.Value = 0 
     
-- Функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на ImageButton 
local function increaseBalance() 
    balance.Value = balance.Value + 1 
    textLabel.Text = "Баланс: " .. balance.Value 
    sound:Play() 
end
     
-- Привязываем функцию к событию MouseButton1Click 
imageButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(increaseBalance)```



local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Player = Players.LocalPlayer
local imageButton = script.Parent.ImageButton 
local textLabel = script.Parent.TextLabel 
local sound = script.Parent.ImageButton.Sound 

local Balance = Player.leaderstats.Balance

local function increaseBalance() 
        textLabel.Text = "Баланс: " .. Balance.Value 
        sound:Play() 
    end
 imageButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
      Remote.ChangeBalance:FireServer()
      increaseBalance()
end)

и тут уже серверный скрипт:
Remote.ChangeBalance.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
      plr.leaderstats.Balance.Value += 1
end)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

хорошо, учту вашу просьбу
